# AWS Lambda - How much CPU does AWS Lambda allocates to my function's provisioned memory?

Tags: aws-lambda

In AWS Lambda documentation, there is no mention on the amount of CPU (GHz) that Amazon allocates to a function, proportionally to its allocated memory.

For example, if I allocate my function 128 MB, 256 MB, 512 MB or 1024 MB, what is the corresponding CPU provisioned in each case?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This study](https://www.sentiatechblog.com/aws-re-invent-2020-day-3-optimizing-lambda-cost-with-multi-threading?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=day3_lambda) shows how the CPU cores scale with the memory config. Unfortunately there are no official numbers being released from AWS.